# Prime factors of given number from editview to textview

Tags: java, android

I am doing an activity in which you you write number in editview (usernumber) and then you get prime factors in textview next to it (primefactor).
i used some strips of code for prime fators but I don't understand it much, so I will be thankful for any help.
EDIT: Did some changes to code as suggested, but code still doesn't do anything:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activityone extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText usernumber;
    TextView primefactor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
        usernumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        primefactor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.primefactor);
        usernumber.addTextChangedListener(prvoWatcher);
    }
    private final TextWatcher prvoWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        double f,
                c;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().equals("")){
                f = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                while (f%2==0)
                {
                    primefactor.setText(2 + " ");
                    f /= 2;
                }

                int i;
                for (i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(f); i+= 2)
                {
                    // While i divides f, print i and divide n
                    while (f%i == 0)
                    {
                        primefactor.setText(i + " ");
                        f /= i;
                    }
                }

                // This condition is to handle the case whien
                // f is a prime number greater than 2
                if (f > 2)
                    primefactor.setText(String.valueOf(f));
            }



        }
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: As Kunu said, in String.valueOf(int);

Answer (score 0):

Error is 
`String.valueOf(int);`

It expects a integer or float variable not the datatype.

Comment: So what should I type there?

Comment: @Jan A variable

Answer (score 0):

```
primefactor.setText(String.valueOf(int));
```

That's not how it works, you can't just put a primitive type in there as an argument. Either replace `int` by `i` or by `f`, depending on what you want to show.

So it looks like

```
primefactor.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

or

```
primefactor.setText(String.valueOf(f));
```

EDIT: Of course, if you want to use the `i` variable, you have to declare if before the for-loop, and not in it.

```
int i;
for (i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(f); i+= 2)
{
    // While i divides n, print i and divide n
    while (f%i == 0)
    {
        primefactor.setText(i + " ");
        f /= i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried it, neither of them work for me.

Comment: How does that not work for you? It removes the error, right?

Comment: Yes, it removes error, but it still doesn't show any number.

Comment: Does your code even get there then? Have you tried using the debugger, setting a break point to different lines?

Comment: I can't check it, for some reason my phone freezes with waiting for debugger screen.

Comment: It is normal for a program to freeze when it's getting debugged, because its thread is getting suspended. But then you should be able to see where your program has stopped, if it has stopped, in your IDE. You can inspect current variables and go forward step by step.

Answer (score 0):

```
primefactor.setText(String.valueOf(int));
```

What's the int ?